# Auto refresh of online users table without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table displaying the list of online and offline users in my dashboard page. I'm trying to automatically refresh the entire table every 5 seconds to show if there are other users who just logged in or out without refreshing the whole page. I have searched through different threads and pages regarding this which is telling me to use AJAX or JSP. But I can't seem to make it work.

This is my table:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
        $online = DB::table('users')->where('group_id', $user->group_id)->orderBy('online', 'desc')->get();
        foreach($online as $val=>$key)
        { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php if ($key->online == 1) { echo '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>'; } else { echo '<span class="label label-warning">Offline</span>'; } ?></td>
            <td><?=$key->first_name." ".$key->last_name?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I found this code on a different thread, but when I tried to use it on my project, it wasn't loading the data in my table. I'm not very familiar working with javascripts or AJAX, so I'm hoping you can help me out. It'll be very much appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#refresh").click(function() 
        {
            $("#Container").load("content-that-needs-to-refresh.php");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="Container">
<?php include('content-that-needs-to-refresh.php'); ?>
</div>
<a href="#" id="refresh">Refresh</a>
```

Comment: if you want to reload automatically after every 5 seconds then use `setTimeout`. But I don't understand the concept of `#refresh` click here when you want it automatically! And I assume that your `content-that-needs-to-refresh.php` contains the `table` which you want to load right?

Comment: So did the code you posted load your table once and are you asking how to update it, or it never worked? Just to verify (as you mentioned that you aren't familiar with JS) did you load the jquery lib on your page?

Answer (score 3):

In your case perfectly working for you.

```
setInterval(function()
{
   //call ajax here..for your table result
}
}, 3000);
```

and then ajax will giving you result every 3 second.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you loaded jQuery. You can use Google CDN or save it and load it on your own server.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var refreshUsers = setInterval(function() {
            $("#Container").load("content-that-needs-to-refresh.php");
        }, 5000); // 5000 ms = 5 sec
    });
</script>

<div id="Container">
<?php include('content-that-needs-to-refresh.php'); ?>
</div>
```

If you should want to stop refreshing, use

```
clearInterval(refreshUsers);
```